# How to Convert a string received from dynamics CRM to Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm dynamics CRM developer an I'm writing a codeactivity where I'm receiving field value in format like:

```
[{"name":"Sherlock","id":"a10ef25"}]
```

I want to convert this value to dictionary format. I'm thinking of using `ToDictionary()` method after removing the [] from the value by converting it to string like this:

```
{"name":"Sherlock","exid":"a10ef25"}
```

I need the value of Key which contains "id" but the number of pairs in the string can be more than 2 also some times like:

```
{"name":"Sherlock","id":"a10ef25","date":"25062019"}.

var value=[{"name":"Sherlock","id":"a10ef25"}]; // i'm receiving it from crm & converting to string
var dict=value.Substring(1.value.Length-1);
```

I'm unable to go forward than this. can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more solution

```
var value ="[{ \"name\":\"Sherlock\",\"id\":\"a10ef25\"}]".TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']');
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(value);
var id = dict["id"]; // or dict.TryGetValue("id", out string id);
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks pretty much as json, so you can try just deserialize it to a collection of `Dictionary<string, string>`. With Newtonsoft Json.NET it will look like this:

```
string value = "[{\"name\":\"Sherlock\",\"id\":\"a10ef25\"}]"; // the original value, no need to trim/remove
var collectionOfDicts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string,string>>>(value);
```

To get the key which contains id you can manipulate the collection, for example like this:

```
var id = collectionOfDicts
    .FirstOrDefault()
    ?.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.Contains("id", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .Select(kvp => kvp.Value)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

**UPD**

Another option would be using [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) from the same library:

```
var id = JArray.Parse(value)
    .Descendants()
    .OfType<JProperty>()
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.Contains("id", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    ?.Value
```

Comment: So very close. You probably need to test this before posting.

Comment: @Enigmativity was editing the question - originally the string was inline.

Answer (score 0):

This is JSON format
Use Json Converter

```
 var value= @"{""name"":""Sherlock"",""id"":""a10ef25"",""date"":""25062019""}";
           
var dict= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(value);
```

Comment: It will not work) the root object is array of object

Comment: copy and paste an example please

Comment: Copy-pasted. It will not even compile.

Comment: Still will not compile.

Comment: i can see you edited your question. so you want only the value of the Id ?

Comment: It is not my question.

Comment: @KrushnaKumar can there be multiple keys with id?

Comment: instead of dictionary you can use List<string> for example ?

Comment: @AlaaMohammed - Did you test this before posting?

Comment: no only one key which includes the string id. i mean the it was coming like extid sometimes or as projectid sometimes but only one key will contain "id" word.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes i edited and i tested it . its working

Comment: +  [0] {[name, Sherlock]} 
+  [1] {[id, a10ef25]} 
+  [2] {[date, 25062019]}